# Is there a tendency to name money after other things?

Tags: semantics, reference-request, cross-linguistic, sociolinguistics

Back in Spanish.StackExchange there was a question about the use of the word *plata* (literally "silver") in American dialects of Spanish instead of the proper word, *dinero*. European Spanish also avoids *dinero*, preferring the term *pasta* (lit. "paste"). There are a lot of other, more localized terms like those. Nobody uses *dinero* except in formal contexts. I was intrigued by this because it looked like some widespread phenomenon.

There's a tendency in Spanish, and even more so in English, to name certain banknotes and multiples of currency units with special terms, but this is not it. There's also a taboo, in certain cultures, against speaking of money, but that doesn't mean money cannot be mentioned, only that asking someone about their income, for example, is viewed as impolite.

Is there **a recognized tendency to name money after other things** (such as precious metals) to the point of almost replacing, in most conversations, the proper term for "money"? Has it been studied cross-linguistically?

Comment: There definitely is a tendency.  Maybe edit the title of the question to match the actual question at the end?

Comment: In Akkadian, "to pay" is *kaspam nadānum*, literally "to give silver", or *kaspam šaqālum*, literally "to weigh out silver". However I don't think there even *is* a generic word for "money", so it probably reflects bleaching of the term (from "silver" to "money") rather than avoiding taboo.

Comment: In Romanian, *plata* means *payment*.

Comment: The fact that *money*, *Geld*, *argent* shows that there's historically no fixed term. That might look like taboo, I don't know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although anecdotally the answer to the question is a confident "yes", there is a big complication: the many concepts of *economic value* that are bundled into the Western European concept of "money". This of course is a question for historical economics and anthropology, more than linguistics.

A related question would be the [question](https://elaineou.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Grierson-The-Origins-of-Money.pdf) of [the origins of the words for money](https://www.reddit.com/r/europe/comments/5qczk3/the_origins_of_the_word_money_in_various_european/). This often relates to the following:

- The physical manifestation of the currency system, whether that's "silver" (as in French *argent*, Thai เงิน *ngoen*, Irish *airgead*, Tibetan དངུལ *dngul*), "metal" (as in Japanese *かね, kane*), "cattle" (as in Classical Latin *pecunia*, Old English *feoh* [modern English *fee*]) or "squirrel pelts" (Finnish *raha*).
- The location or characteristics of a specific currency (for example the temple of Juno Moneta in Rome, giving rise to English *money*; or the one-tenth nature of the denarius, producing Spanish *dinero*; or the "solid" nature of the solidus gold coin, producing Italian *soldi*; a northern European ancestor of "penny", giving rise to Swedish *pengar* as well as Czech *peníze*; Swahili *shilingi* from the pre-decimal British currency and *pesa* from the Indian currency).
- The verbs to do with nature of currency, including giving (whence German *Geld*) or desiring (giving rise to Modern Greek *χρήμα, khríma*) or taking (such as Latvian *nauda*).
- A generic word for "thing", often leading to "value" and thence to "money" (e.g. Bengali অর্থ *ôrthô*).

However, there are many origins which are still very much under debate, where we can only reconstruct ancient forms and then tentatively attach them to possible roots (e.g. Chinese 錢 [Mandarin *qián*, Cantonese *cin4*2*], possibly related to spades/knives or the Classical Chinese word for thin; Korean 돈 *don*, possibly related to the verb for "to turn").

I think the question can be rephrased slightly:

- Is the semantic field of "money" more susceptible to change than average?

Again, the evident answer [is "yes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang_terms_for_money), because of its [ubiquity in daily life](https://repozytorium.ur.edu.pl/handle/item/2735) but also its [large power](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248968346_Meanings_of_money_national_identity_and_the_semantics_of_currency_in_Zambia_and_Tanzania). Although top-down changes like the Zambia / Tanzania example are rare, the "[emotionally charged nature](https://blog.online-spellcheck.com/english/95-slang-words-money-meanings/)" means [that](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/00754240022004947):

> the semantic field of money is often taken to be one of the most fertile areas of word formation in slang[.]

Although I've not (yet?) seen any denigration of a formal word for "money" due to taboo (although in modern Japanese the rise of お金 *o-kane* as a polite form for 金 *kane* may attest to this), there are plenty of [euphemisms](https://digilib.k.utb.cz/bitstream/handle/10563/12722/ja%C4%8Dkov%C3%A1_2010_bp.pdf) for types of *debt* and [other adverse economic situations](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=xbouDwAAQBAJ). More commonly for "money" itself, it is [expressivity](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=MZYgAAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA61) that is desired, and hence metaphor and metonymy add greater colour to a piece of daily life.

Comment: Tidbit: all of *solidus*, *moneta* and *denarius* made it into Italian: the first, as you said, as *soldi*, the latter two as *moneta* and *denaro* (or less common *danaro*). *Moneta* refers to either a particular currency ("l'Euro è una moneta"), or coins ("ho il portafoglio pieno di monete"); *soldi* and *denaro* are more or less interchangeable in meaning, although *soldi* is more colloquial and *denaro* more formal.